# Structure initialization does not work with malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I've a small background in C that I'm trying to dig up, and I encountered something I can't explain.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct World {
   Things* things;
};
```

and the following functions:

```
void initWorld(World *world);

void addThingToWorld(World *world, Thing *thing);
```

Now, depending on the implementation of `initWorld` and how I use it, it will either work or not. But I don't understand why the second implementation should fail. Both implementations are below:

### First (working) implementation

```
void initWorld(World *world){
    world->things = NULL;
}

// usage
World world;
initWorld(&world);
// will work, because world has been correctly initialized.
addThingToWorld(&world, &something);
```

### Second (failing) implementation

```
void initWorld(World *world){
    world = (World*) malloc(sizeof(World));
    world->things = NULL; // here it does not work! things is not changed to 0x0 :(
}

// usage
World *world;
initWorld(world);
// this will crash as a side-effect of the failed world initialization (world->things has not been correctly set to NULL)
addThingToWorld(world, &something);
```

Thank you for your help, and correct any nonsense I might be doing, my C background is pretty poor at the moment :)

## Edit

Okay I understood the fact that I was passing a pointer to my function in the second case, and re-assigning it with a local malloc so in the end the caller's variable was not changed. However as I was debugging there is still something I don't understand. In the `initWorld` function, the second case, the `world->things` value did not change after the assignation to NULL. **I also tried to rename the local variable** world to "w", I thought that maybe the debugger was displaying the caller's variable "world", but no, `w->things` still was not correctly initialized to NULL.

Any hints?

Comment: what is `Things` here?

Comment: `initWorld` takes its parameter by value (that is, it copies its argument into a local variable). You modify the pointer in `initWorld`, but this pointer is a copy of the one where `initWorld` is being called. To solve the problem either use a pointer a pointer or return the pointer from initWorld.

Comment: `world` is a local variable, a copy of the pointer you pass in. Modifying the pointer itself has no effect on the caller's side. You would have to pass a pointer to a pointer, so that you can refer to the caller's pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, `world` is a pointer to `World`: The things it points to can be altered, but the pointer itself cannot.

You could pass a pointer to pointer to `World` to solve this, but I would prefer to return a pointer if you do allocation inside a function:

```
World *newWorld() 
{
    World *world = malloc(sizeof(*world));

    if (world) world->things = NULL;
    return world;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
World *world = newWorld();
```

Comment: Do you need to put `struct World` everywhere, or does C allow you to omit that these days?

Comment: @Vincent: You mean in your original second example? It may have to do with optimisation: The compiler sees that assignment happens just before the variable goes out of scope and doesn't generate code for it. But that's just a guess; you could compile with optimisation turned off and check.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is like other types, it's passed by value as function parameter. You allocated memory for the (local) parameter `world` in the function, but this doesn't affect `world` in the called function. This causes memory leak, by the way.

Instead, use a pointer to a pointer:

```
void initWorld(World **world){
    *world = malloc(sizeof(World));
    (*world)->things = NULL; 
}
```

And call it:

```
World *world;
initWorld(&world);
```