# Why doesn't this object get set to NULL after the function call?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Person{
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
};

struct Person* create_person(const char* f_name, const char* l_name)
{
    struct Person* new_person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    new_person->first_name = malloc((1+strlen(f_name))*sizeof(char));
    new_person->last_name = malloc((1+strlen(l_name))*sizeof(char));

    strcpy(new_person->first_name, f_name);
    strcpy(new_person->last_name, l_name);

    return new_person;
}

void delete_person(struct Person* person)
{
    free(person->first_name);
    free(person->last_name);
    free(person);

    person->first_name = 0;
    person->last_name = 0;
    person = 0;

    if(person){
        printf("Person not deleted\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Person deleted\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Person* person1 = create_person("John", "Doe");
    delete_person(person1);

    if(person1){
        printf("Person not deleted\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Person deleted\n");
    }
}
```

Program output is:

> Person deleted
>
> Person not deleted

My question is: why doesn't `person1` point to `NULL`? It seems like the memory is freed (because if I try to use it I get an error), but why is the pointer still pointing to something (apparently) valid? Why doesn't `person = 0;` get carried across the function call?

Comment: Perhaps because the parameter into `delete_person` is `person*` not `person**`

Comment: `void delete_person(struct Person* person)` : Copy of the pointer is passed. Also, `person->first_name = 0;` : You may not use the area that has already been freed.

Comment: I thought that pointers were supposed to retain their values regardless. So when person goes out of scope in delete_person, the part where I set everything to 0 is ignored?

Comment: @Bob John: "...doesn't get destroyed"? What made you conclude that? Your object gets successfully destroyed by `free`. As for pointers that pointed to that object originally - that is *your* responsibility to update their values (e.g. set them to null). You never updated your `person1` pointer in `main`. Why do you expect it to suddenly become null?

Comment: @AndreyT I'll update the title. I just thought that if I pass a pointer to a function, then any operations I do on that pointer will successfully translate over the function call.

Comment: Same problem as seen in [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541444/structure-initialization-does-not-work-with-malloc).

Comment: @BobJohn `person` inside `delete_person` is a different variable to `person1` inside `main`. C uses pass-by-value; function parameters are copies of the arguments supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parameter's value change be see outside your function (and not only locally, like you're seeing) you need to take a `struct Person ** person` (note `**`) instead of.

EDIT: note that you're accessing memory which you don't own anymore in:

```
person->first_name = 0;
person->last_name = 0;
```

Because you've already freed `person`

Try this:

```
void delete_person(struct Person ** person)
{
    struct Person *p = *person;

    free(p->first_name);
    free(p->last_name);
    free(*person);

    *person = 0;
}
```

And call using:

```
delete_person(&person1);
```